# How to Get Better Formatting in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I find that formatting that VS does by default is not what I expected it.

I am not sure if I need a plugin or something else.

I am using reactjs(as .js file) and I get weird results in purse js files and in files that mix jsx in it.

example 1

On format I will have something like this

```
create : flow(function* (
   firstName,
   lastName,
   email,
   password,
   phoneNumber,
   userName
) {}),
```

or in a file with jsx

```
 <a
        className="button is-primary"
        onClick={() => console.log()}
  >
        Edit
  </a>
```

Comment: Have you tried [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode)?

Comment: You can change a lot of the default formatting settings in VS itself.  Exhaust those possibilities before trying something 3rd party.

Comment: @Tholle - hmm, I seemed to had it installed. I think that might be what is causing the weird formatting. Maybe I need to tweak something?

Comment: You might have to check the hotkey, or configure "format on save". It's explained in the extension documentation if I remember correctly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but it does seem that Prettier is what is causing the weird formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link https://medium.freecodecamp.org/immensely-upgrade-your-development-environment-with-these-visual-studio-code-extensions-9cd790478530

There have a lot of extensions that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right

[image]

Make sure you set the language to JavaScript React

[image]

(This should be automatic if the extension is .jsx)